# How to replace values in specific rows based on a previous row?

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, row

Currently my dataframe resembles the one below, but with hundreds of similar rows:

```
vol onset   con num signal     sec stim 
2   NA      NA  NA  612.7394    4   0  
3   5.32    neg 1   611.7746    6   0   
4   NA      NA  NA  612.7696    8   0   
5   NA      NA  NA  612.6067    10  0   
6   11.54   mb  3   615.3129    12  1   
7   NA      NA  NA  613.9639    14  0   
8   NA      NA  NA  615.4326    16  0   
9   NA      NA  NA  613.9639    18  0   
10  NA      NA  NA  615.4326    20  0   
11  21.48   neg 2   613.9639    22  0   
12  NA      NA  NA  615.4326    24  0   
13  NA      NA  NA  613.9639    26  0   
14  NA      NA  NA  615.4326    28  0
```

Here, `stim` is equal to 1 when `num` is equal to 3; otherwise, `stim` is equal to zero.

However, I would like the value of `stim` in the subsequent two rows to *also* equal 1 when `num` is equal to 3. I would also like the values for `con` and `num`to carry down to those two rows, as shown below.

```
vol onset   con num signal     sec stim 
2   NA      NA  NA  612.7394    4   0  
3   5.32    neg 1   611.7746    6   0   
4   NA      NA  NA  612.7696    8   0   
5   NA      NA  NA  612.6067    10  0   
6   11.54   mb  3   615.3129    12  1   
7   NA      mb  3   613.9639    14  1   
8   NA      mb  3   615.4326    16  1   
9   NA      NA  NA  613.9639    18  0   
10  NA      NA  NA  615.4326    20  0   
11  21.48   neg 2   613.9639    22  0   
12  NA      NA  NA  615.4326    24  0   
13  NA      NA  NA  613.9639    26  0   
14  NA      NA  NA  615.4326    28  0
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lag` and `lead` function from `dplyr` -

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>%
  mutate(stim = as.integer(lag(stim) == 1 | stim == 1 | lead(stim) == 1), 
         num = replace(num, stim == 1, 3))
df

#   vol onset  con num   signal sec stim
#1    2    NA <NA>  NA 612.7394   4   NA
#2    3  5.32  neg   1 611.7746   6    0
#3    4    NA <NA>  NA 612.7696   8    0
#4    5    NA <NA>   3 612.6067  10    1
#5    6 11.54   mb   3 615.3129  12    1
#6    7    NA <NA>   3 613.9639  14    1
#7    8    NA <NA>  NA 615.4326  16    0
#8    9    NA <NA>  NA 613.9639  18    0
#9   10    NA <NA>  NA 615.4326  20    0
#10  11 21.48  neg   2 613.9639  22    0
#11  12    NA <NA>  NA 615.4326  24    0
#12  13    NA <NA>  NA 613.9639  26    0
#13  14    NA <NA>  NA 615.4326  28   NA
```

---

Or perhaps simpler in base R -

```
inds <- which(df$stim == 1)
df$stim[c(inds-1, inds + 1)] <- 1
df$num[df$stim == 1] <- 3
```